# Check IP address of users connecting and compare to database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to check the stored IP address of users when logging in, and compare with what is stored in the database. The IP address is being stored in the Comment column of the default aspnetdb.

The email is sending every time the user connects even if the IP address is the same. I would only like the email to send when the IP address is different than what is stored.

```
    Protected Sub LoginUser_LoggingIn(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoggingIn

    Dim CurrentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(LoginUser.UserName)

    If (CurrentUser IsNot Nothing) Then

        Dim IPAddress As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress

        Dim CurrentIP As String = CurrentUser.Comment

        If (IPAddress IsNot CurrentIP) Then

            Dim IP_Change As New Thread(
                Sub()
                    Dim mailObject As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
                    Dim emailCredentials As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("my@domain.com", "password")

                    mailObject.Subject = "User " & CurrentUser.ToString & " is connecting from a new IP Address ( " & IPAddress & " )"
                    mailObject.Body = "User is connecting from a new IP Address"

                    mailObject.To.Add("my@email.com")
                    mailObject.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("my@domain.com")
                    mailObject.IsBodyHtml = True

                    Dim SmtpMail As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("my.domain.com")
                    SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                    SmtpMail.EnableSsl = False
                    SmtpMail.Credentials = emailCredentials
                    SmtpMail.Port = 587
                    SmtpMail.Send(mailObject)
                End Sub
            )
            IP_Change.Start()

            CurrentUser.Comment = IPAddress
            Membership.UpdateUser(CurrentUser)

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you're running into an inconsistency with the behavior of `IsNot` due to reference comparisons.

Change your comparison to something like this: `If (IPAddress <> CurrentIP) Then` and it should work.

Comment: `IsNot` compares by reference. Since the two strings have different references `IsNot` returns false. Using `<>` does a comparison by value.